# How can I make this airfoil/wing with the help of a Bezier curve without having to turn it into a mesh in Blender 2.79b?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, conversion

Is there a way I can turn this airfoil here, into a wing?

I made the wing by converting the curve into a mesh, and then extruding it, but of course I lost the very useful handes of the curve.

How can I make the same wing, without having to convert the curve into a mesh?
I need to extrude the curve but, when I do it using the right hand side panel, it just extrudes it into uniformally, without giving me more handles alongside it to be able to change its shape along the way.

I know I can always turn it into a mesh, the way I did it for the wing in the image but keeping it a "curve" with its handles would be desirable in the long-run.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot model complex shapes in Blender using curves(with handles) only without any add-ons. It is possible to use NURBS, but NURBS surface curves do not have handles on their points.

There is however an add-on [Animation Nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/releases/tag/v2.0) that provides more procedural modelling functionality and you could construct a surface out of curve splines using loft function. This way you could keep the curves and their handles that influence the shape of the surface. These would be the nodes needed:

[image]

Comment: Hi Martin. I think I will go the way of converting the curve into a mesh instead. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: Well, you did ask how you can model it while keeping the curves and their handles. I believe I did answer that. What you decide to do with the answer seems to be entirely your choice.